# Can we map excel row to SharePoint Lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, custom-list

I am looking for a feature if we could map an excel rows in `SharePoint`  or any other mechanism to generate an email after row in excel has been changed.

**Problem **

Our customer uses `SharePoint` to share an excel file which contains list of Methods that needs to be implemented with each one has its own statuses as , Proposed, Inprogress , Implemented , Changed . Every developer (Offshore and onsite even the customer) will have an access to this excel and they would change it and some times forget to email the changes that they have done . I have looked up in the internet to know if there is an feature available in `SharePoint` to generate an automated email once the excel is updated with the row number .

So far i have seen we can sync the data from an excel to Custom list but this is not exactly what i wanted. Any solutions ? or atleast put me in right direction so that i could find a solution for this problem

Comment: Yeah, use a proper issue tracker

Comment: @MdMazzotti , thanks for the comment please understand i was only asking for a very specific feature or any guidance to put me in a path where i could find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any oob sharepoint functionaliteis that captures changes in excel. You can follow either of the two approaches below.

1. If you sync the excel file to a sharepoint list, it would be extremely easy to co-ordinate issue tracking. (I know this is what you want, but it would simply make things a lot easier and would help you leverage sharepoint better). Simply have a custom list that you can sync sharepoint data to. And implement a basic sharepoint designer workflow that sends mail on item updated.
    [Sending Emails from SPD workflows](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/161761.aspx) 
    
   [Workflow Events Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj650894.aspx)
2. If you only wanna use excel emailing capabilities, then you need to go with excel macros. This [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203718(v=office.11).aspx#odc_sendingmailinexcel) is a great source if you wanna learn about excel email capabilities.

Comment: thanks for the answer , i would prefer the excel macro over a custom list .